# Getting variable values from variable names listed in array in Bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to print values of multiple variables that are listed in a Bash array as evident in the minimal code example below.

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR1="/path/to/source/root"
VAR2="/path/to/target/root"
VAR3="50"

VARS=("VAR1" "VAR2" "VAR3")
for var in ${VARS[*]}; do
    echo "value of $var is ${$var}"
done
```

This gives me an error

```
line 8: value of $var is ${$var}: bad substitution
```

I want the following output:

```
value of VAR1 is /path/to/source/root
value of VAR2 is /path/to/target/root
value of VAR3 is 50
```

My search on Google and SO was not very fruitful. Because of the indirection (i.e., `var` iterates over an array containing *names* of variables for which I want the *values*), I'm not able to precisely word my search. But any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use indirect reference as:

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR1="/path/to/source/root"
VAR2="/path/to/target/root"
VAR3="50"

VARS=("VAR1" "VAR2" "VAR3")
for var in ${VARS[*]}; do
    echo "value of $var is ${!var}"
done
```

**Output:**

```
value of VAR1 is /path/to/source/root
value of VAR2 is /path/to/target/root
value of VAR3 is 50
```