# Get variable name while iterating over array in bash

Tags: linux, bash

What I have is an array with some variables. I can iterate to get the values of those vars but what I need is actually their names (values will be used elsewhere).

Going with var[i] won't work cause I will have different names. I guess I could workaround this by creating another array with the names - something similar to this:
[Getting variable values from variable names listed in array in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307073/getting-variable-values-from-variable-names-listed-in-array-in-bash)

But I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this.

```
var1=$'1'
var2=$'2'
var3=$'3'

Array=( $var1 $var2 $var3)

for ((i=0; i<${#Array[@]}; i++))
do
  echo ${Array[i]}
done
```

Is:

```
>1
>2
>3
```

Should be:

```
>var1
>var2
>var3
```

Comment: Why don't you just store the strings `var1` `var2` `var3` in your array?

Comment: `var1=1; var2=2; var3=3; Array=( $var2 $var2 $var3 )` results in `Array=( 1 2 3 )`. The entries aren't linked to variables in any significant way -- if you then afterwards ran `var1=4; var2=5; var3=6`, the array would *still* be `1 2 3`; as such, there isn't any metadata to retrieve.

Comment: (and `$'1'` is **exactly** the same as `1`; there's no point whatsoever to using the alternate literal syntax here -- in most of the cases where there *was* a point to using that syntax, you'd need to make it `Array=( "$var1" "$var2" "$var3" )` to avoid munging your data during the assignment).

Comment: BTW, a language that *did* allow what you're asking for would be exceedingly rare. In Python, for example, if you set `var1=1; var2=2; var3=3; Array=[ var1, var2, var3 ]`, you can't get back from `Array[0]`'s value of `1` to the variable `var1` it was originally taken from (especially since `var1` may no longer *have the value `1`* at the future point in time when the inspection is desired).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want an associative array.

```
# to set values over time
declare -A Array=( ) || { echo "ERROR: Need bash 4.0 or newer" >&2; exit 1; }
Array[var1]=1
Array[var2]=2
Array[var3]=3
```

This can also be assigned at once:

```
# or as just one assignment
declare -A Array=( [var1]=1 [var2]=2 [var3]=3 )
```

Either way, one can iterate over the keys with `"${!Array[@]}"`, and retrieve the value for a key with `${Array[key]}`:

```
for var in "${!Array[@]}"; do
  val="${Array[$var]}"
  echo "$var -> $val"
done
```

...will, after either of the assignments up top, properly emit:

```
var1 -> 1
var2 -> 2
var3 -> 3
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this solution?

```
#!/bin/bash

var1=$'1'
var2=$'2'
var3=$'3'

Array=( var1 var2 var3 )

for var in "${Array[@]}"; do
  echo "$var = ${!var}"
done
```

The idea just consists in putting your variable names in the array, then relying on the [indirection](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#indirection) feature of Bash.

But as pointed out by @CharlesDuffy, the use of associative arrays sounds better adapted to the OP's use case.

Also, this related article may be worth reading: [How can I use variable variables… or associative arrays?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006)

Comment: The OP's question links to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307073/getting-variable-values-from-variable-names-listed-in-array-in-bash showing exactly this technique, so I believe they're already familiar with it.